# Credible interval estimation for a difference of paired binomials

Tags: bayesian, binomial-distribution, paired-data, credible-interval

Assume one is given two series of binomially distributed data:
$$X_{1k} \sim Binom(n_{1k}, p_{1k})$$
$$X_{2k} \sim Binom(n_{2k}, p_{2k})$$
$$k\in \{1\ldots K\}$$
The goal is to estimate $p_2 - p_1$ along with it's credible interval, given some priors on $p_1$ and $p_2$. Similarly to the paired $t$-test, I'd expect the resultant credible interval to be smaller when $X_{1k}$ and $X_{2k}$ are strongly correlated, and thus the motivation of not simply estimating the credible interval from the sums.

However, I have not been able to find any sources as to how to calculate this credible interval. Are there any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that usually works quite well is to use a Bayesian approach, because you can exactly write down your hypothesized data-generating-process as your likelihood, set priors (if you don't really want priors, make them vague). This approach often even has very good small sample properties as a frequentist method. Importantly, fitting a Bayesian model and then transforming model parameters deals really well with things like inference about differences of proportions (as opposed to, say, log-odds ratios).

In general, something like [Stan](https://mc-stan.org/) let's you write down almost any model (as long as you don't have discrete parameters that can't easily be integrated out). Alternatively, higher level-interfaces like [`brms`](https://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/) should actually be able to handle a relatively simple case like this one. E.g. code like the following could work, if you want to answer the question of this difference in a new randomly drawn member of the population:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(brms)

example <- tibble(y = c(10, 20, 1, 2, 4, 8, 12, 24),
                  n = c(30, 30, 3, 3, 12, 24, 15, 30),
                  question=factor(c(1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L)),
                  subject=factor(rep(1L:4L, each=2)))

brmfit1 <- brm( y | trials(n) ~ 0 + question + (0+question|subject),
                family = binomial(link="logit"),
                data = example,
                prior = prior(class=b, normal(0, 3.14)) +
                  prior(class=sd, normal(0, 5)),
                backend="cmdstanr", 
                control=list(adapt_delta=0.99))

pseudo_samples <- 1e25
preds <- posterior_predict( brmfit1, newdata=tibble(question=1L:2L, subject=5L, n=pseudo_samples),
                   allow_new_levels=T, sample_new_levels="gaussian") %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(delta = V2/pseudo_samples - V1/pseudo_samples) 

quantile(preds$delta, probs=c(0.5, 0.025, 0.975))
# One example run gave:
#        50%       2.5%      97.5% 
#  0.1203225 -0.6870735  0.8045677 

preds %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=delta)) +
  geom_density(fill=rgb(0.1,0.1,1.0,0.5))
```

[image: Posterior density for the difference]

Comment: Unclear to me if the proposed model makes sense, since the variables are correlated. Wishart distribution?

Comment: Notice the correlated random effects that attempt to capture that. If you just have two endpoints, it just comes down to a single correlation.